# Keras / Theano exceptions are getting masked

Tags: keras, theano

I am using an evolutionary algorithm to find satisfactory hyper-parameters for a CNN written in Keras/Theano.  The stochastic nature of this approach means that from time to time a pathological configuration will be tried, which will yield an exception.  In those scenarios, I'd like to catch the exception so I can assign an appropriate low fitness.  Unfortunately, when Theano throws an exception, it appears to be masked before it reaches my try/catch block.  That is, at some point the exception is caught and not re-raised, which means it never propagates up the stack to reach my try/catch block.

I've asked on the Keras Slack workspace if there was some configuration I had to tickle in Keras to un-mask these exceptions, but I was told that the problem was not at the Keras level, that it was something with Theano.  And, so here I am.

I have the following configuration settings at the top of the corresponding theanorc file that I had hoped would solve the problem:

```python
[config]
on_opt_error = raise
on_shape_error = raise
numpy.seterr_all = raise
compute_test_value = raise
```

And, these are the exceptions I am seeing:

```python
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): SeqOptimizer apply <theano.tensor.opt.ShapeOptimizer object at 0x2aaae03674a8>
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/gof/opt.py", line 235, in apply
    sub_prof = optimizer.optimize(fgraph)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/gof/opt.py", line 83, in optimize
    self.add_requirements(fgraph)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/tensor/opt.py", line 1482, in add_requirements
    fgraph.attach_feature(ShapeFeature())
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/gof/fg.py", line 541, in attach_feature
    attach(self)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/tensor/opt.py", line 1299, in on_attach
    self.on_import(fgraph, node, reason='on_attach')
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/tensor/opt.py", line 1362, in on_import
    self.set_shape(r, s)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/tensor/opt.py", line 1151, in set_shape
    shape_vars.append(self.unpack(s[i], r))
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/theano/tensor/opt.py", line 1073, in unpack
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: There is a negative shape in the graph!
Backtrace when that variable is created:

  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/mcoletti/dl-4-settlement-mapping/eadl/train_cnn.py", line 218, in <module>
    validation_accuracy = train_cnn(data_dir=args.data_dir, kernel_sizes=args.kernel_sizes, max_epoch=args.epoch, batch_sizes=args.batch_size)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/mcoletti/dl-4-settlement-mapping/eadl/train_cnn.py", line 193, in train_cnn
    model = create_cnn(kernel_sizes=kernel_sizes)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/mcoletti/dl-4-settlement-mapping/eadl/train_cnn.py", line 52, in create_cnn
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=kernel_sizes[3], activation="relu", kernel_initializer="normal"))
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/keras/models.py", line 475, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/keras/engine/topology.py", line 602, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 164, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/ccs/proj/geo121/python3.5-packages/dl4sm/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1890, in conv2d
    filter_dilation=dilation_rate)
```

And, if you're curious to see the try/catch block, it's just this:

```python
   try:
        validation_accuracy = train_cnn(data_dir=args.data_dir, kernel_sizes=args.kernel_sizes, max_epoch=args.epoch, batch_sizes=args.batch_size)
   except Exception as e:
        print(socket.gethostname(), ', Caught exception while training:', str(e) )
```

My intuition is that this is probably something very, very simple.  Maybe I need to add more options to the THEANORC file?

Comment: Adding this lines *may* have done the job:

`theano.config.compute_test_value = 'raise'`

Answer (score 0):

Setting `theano.config.compute_test_value = 'raise'` appears to work.

Curiously, `compute_test_value` should have been set from the Theano configuration file, which suggests that it's not being properly read and parsed. I should not have to set this value programmatically when I explicitly set it in the configuration file.